# Extract first 2 digits of a number using python

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, numpy

Hi I have an array of numbers which is in UTC format.The format is HH.MM.SS.MS i.e hours minutes seconds and milliseconds. I want to convert the entire number to milliseconds . So I am extracting first 2 digits like below

```
hh=int(str(x[1])[:2]) # returns 42 where  hours and minutes mixed

# My data also start with non zero for example x=142826.00
  # doing the same operation like above returns 14( It is perfect). So intention is when 04 extract only 4 and if it is 14 extract 14.


042826.00
042826.25
042826.50
042826.75
042827.00
042827.25
042827.50
042827.75
042828.00
042828.25
042828.50
042828.75
042829.00
042829.25
042829.50
042829.75
042830.00
042830.25
042830.50
042830.75
```

How to extract and convert to milliseconds .

Comment: Why do you have them as numbers if they're not numbers?

Comment: And you get it as numbers instead of text?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams. Yes

Comment: First you need to understand the type of your data, what you get if you `print(type(x))`? Are you sure the data are in `int` instead of 'str'? As if they are `int`, there won't be any prefix `0`, `042826.00` will simply be displayed as `42826.0`.

Comment: @hcheung. Understood .It is float but hours changes from 1 digit to 2 digit format .i.e sometimes 5 hours and 11 hours depending upon the duration of data.

Comment: If it is `float`, then it is just a simple multification to convert it to milliseconds...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would save yourself a lot of trouble and work with the nice formatting options already supplied by `pandas.to_datetime`. Your column is clearly a string because of the leading zeros. From there, it's very easy to get a the time in any unit you want, in this case `'ms'`

The format of your string is `'%H%M%S.%f'`. We'll convert this to a `datetime` object which gives you the starting date `1900-01-01`. We just subtract that off and then convert the units to ms with `np.timedelta64`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df
       number
0   042826.00
1   042826.25
2   042826.50
3   042826.75
4   042827.00
5   042827.25
6   042827.50
7   042827.75

(pd.to_datetime(df.number, format='%H%M%S.%f')
 -pd.to_datetime('1900-01-01'))/np.timedelta64(1, 'ms')
#0     16106000.0
#1     16106250.0
#2     16106500.0
#3     16106750.0
#4     16107000.0
#5     16107250.0
#6     16107500.0
#7     16107750.0
#Name: number, dtype: float64
```

The Date `1900-01-01` is used as the default most likely because of the default behavior of [time.strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strptime)

> The default values used to fill in any missing data when more accurate values cannot be inferred are (1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1). Both string and format must be strings.

Comment: @Poka see my edit as to why 1900-01-01 is the default time.

Comment: @Poka Dividing by `np.timedelta64(1, 'ms')` is a standard way to do unit conversions to that timeunit, in this case `ms` See [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html#datetime-and-timedelta-arithmetic)

Comment: @Poka I'm not sure. The data above works whether it's numeric of string. On your whole dataset there must be some bad entries. If there are a lot of leading zeros, imagine a field that is `000041.12` you're going to have a format error when it's converted to just `41.12` through `pd.to_numeric` because that does not match the specified format we provided. Best to leave them as string in this case before converting, since that datatype preserves the original formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to change them back and forth in `str` and `int`.
First use `Decimal/float` to get the millisecond then use `int` to convert the rest:

```
numbers = {your array}
milisecond = 0
for number in numbers:
    number = Decimal(number, '.3f')
    millisecond += (number * 1000) % 1000
    number = int(number)
    millisecond += (number % 100) * 1000
    number /= 100
    millisecond += (number % 100) * 60 * 1000
    number /= 100
    millisecond += number * 60 * 60 * 1000
```

The `millisecond` is milliseconds you get from the number

Comment: Is it possible to convert the entire array at one shot using loop.

Comment: Update my answer. The `milliseconds` will be summary of all the numbers ( it's will be huge, maybe you need to use `long` for `milliseconds` to handle it)